# Use of undeclared type 'GraphRequestResult' after update of pods

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the new facebook graph request and after updating pods I get an error

> < Use of undeclared type 'GraphRequestResult'>

```
let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: kGraphPathMe, parameters: ["fields":"id,email,last_name,first_name,picture"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: .init(), httpMethod: .get) 

graphRequest.start {(response: HTTPURLResponse?, result: GraphRequestResult<GraphRequest>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let graphResponse):
            if let dictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                completion(FacebookUser(jsonDict: dictionary))
            }
            break
        default:
            print("Facebook request user error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> check this code

```
        let parameters = ["fields": "email, id, name"]
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters)

        _ = graphRequest?.start { [weak self] connection, result, error in
            // If something went wrong, we're logged out
            if (error != nil) {
                // Clear email, but ignore error for now
                return
            }

            // Transform to dictionary first
            if let result = result as? [String: Any] {
                // Got the email; send it to Lucid's server
                guard let email = result["email"] as? String else {
                    // No email? Fail the login
                    return
                }
                guard let username = result["name"] as? String else {
                    // No username? Fail the login
                    return
                }

                guard let userId = result["id"] as? String else {
                    // No userId? Fail the login
                    return
                }                       
            }
        } // End of graph request
```